# Changing an assoc array value in PHP loop where key equals something

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a situation where I am looping through a result set from the DB in MYSQL:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY repID") or die('Query failed!');
while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {

    if(!$flag) {
       // display field/column names as first row
       fputcsv($out, array_keys($row), ',', '"');
       $flag = true;
    }

    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');

    fputcsv($out, array_values($row), ',', '"');
}
```

So this prints out the array keys as column headers for the first row.

In some rows I have ID's that come directly out of the table, so I need to replace the values in specific rows with a function to use the given ID as a search parameter in a DB query.

I just cant seem to find a way to change the array value of a specific column within the loop... any ideas?

Comment: `$row['ID'] = 'new value'`?

Comment: you should be able to use `array_walk` for this...

Comment: how does the `cleanData` method definition look like? Are you passing the `$row` by value or by reference?

Comment: Sorry @marc b was right, I was just being stupid. Getting confused with renaming keys. Obviously changing the value would be easy. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ampersand modifier with the foreach loop as follows.

```
$nameArray = array('test1', 'test2', 'test1');    

foreach ($nameArray as &$value) 
    {
        if ($value === "test1") 
        {
            $value = 'test2';
        }
    }
```